# How to say 'I think so"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words

I was wondering how to say *I think so* in Japanese, do you have to say 'watashi wa kore ga omoimasu' or a different thing?

Comment: 私はそう思う is how I would say it, but there may be a more common way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> そう思うよ/そう思いますよ。 (sou omou yo / sou omoimasu yo.) - closer to "I think so.".
>
> そうだね/そうですね。（sou da ne / sou desu ne.) - That's right.
>
> そうなんだ。（sou nanda.) - That's right. (but with more emphasis).

In the conversation context it is explicit that you're the one saying so there's no need to use 私は、僕は、俺は at the beginning.

Comment: そうだと思う is also an option.

Comment: You're right, is actually more grammar correct using da after sou but I see people usually dropping it

Comment: 私は etc can be added for emphasis, but usually it should be understood implicitly.

Comment: @bjorn in that case wouldn't you use 私が? So you'd say  IT'S ME who think so (not anyone else).